# Suggesting page breaks doesn't seem to work

Tags: page-breaking

I'd like to suggest LaTeX pagebreaks, so that my page won't break right after a headline, but still not make the pagebreak mandatory, leading to blank half-pages in case my document changes.

The commands `\pagebreak[3]` up to and including strength 3 do not seem to do anything, and strength 4 just inserts a forced pagebreak as in `\pagebreak`.

Any way to get a suggested pagebreak?

Comment: Welcome :) could you provide a working example? You can use packages like `lipsum` to generate "random" text to show what you mean.

Comment: Sorry, that's fairly difficult, because the last object on that page is a tikzpicture, which refers to a data file. And the example wouldn't really show the problem unless compiled in the same file. I hoped the problem is well-known.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it the right way. For whatever reason TeX comes to the conclusion that nonetheless a pagebreak at this point were not optimal.

Usually TeX preferes a pagebreak right before a heading. If it doesn't do that even despite the `\pagebreak[3]`, you included code that prevents a pagebreak. Something like `\enlargethispage{3in}`.

Maybe you even provided the wrong papersize, whatever, we can't help you without more information.

By the way, I improve pagebreaks after finishing writing, not during the process.

A nice package to do this is `setspace`. Playing around with `\begin{spacing}{1.0X}`, while X = 0-9, often gives a better result without readers even notice the different spacing.

And while we are at it: load the microtype package.